# spring boot thymeleaf cannot find resources due to URL text

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My spring boot controller url is not able to find the static resources(css, js, etc) when redirecting to a different url(error-page)

Controller URL: http://localhost:8080/document/{someId}
Redirect URL: error-page

When there an error in my controller then I am redirecting the page to error-page.

Since the controller URL contains the '/document' when I redirect the page to error page the resources are not loading. I looked up in the console and saw the 404 issue with following urls:

```
http://localhost:8080/document/styles.css
http://localhost:8080/document/newstyles.css
http://localhost:8080/document/bootstrap.js
```

So I see the word '/document' here is causing the issue.

So my questions is: Is there a way to remove /document from the URL? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error page Thymeleaf template must use `@{xxx}` to build the URLs to the `.css` and `.js` files, because you don't know the base URL.

See section [4.4 Link URLs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls) in the Thymeleaf documentation,

Comment: Andreas, I was missing forward slash for the relative URL's. So instead of using th:href="@{/styles.css}", I was using th:href="@{styles.css}". Thank you for the answer